# How to display image using flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

**models.py**

***Here I can store data***

```
class AddNote(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True)
    description = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)
    img_name = db.Column(db.String(32))
    img = db.Column(db.LargeBinary)
```

**routes.py**

***Retrieving data from database***

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    notes = AddNote.query.all()
    return render_template('index.html', title='NoteBook', notes=notes)
```

**Html template**

***how can I display the image in img tag***

```
{% for note in notes %}
    
        <img src="" class="card-img-top">
        
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if the DB images are stored in static a simple static request should do

```
<img src="{{ url_for('static',filename='{{note.img_name}}') }}"></img>
```

Comment: It cant be store in a static file.